# How to create mpeg video from images in java

Tags: java, jpeg, mpeg-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: How do I create a movie from an array of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856757/java-how-do-i-create-a-movie-from-an-array-of-images)

I have set of images in JPEG format that I want to convert into MPEG video with Java.
How can it be done?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11966968/1007273 could be what you need...

Comment: Actaully i got code for avi video but i want to create video in MPEG format....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Xuggler project: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

Comment: This link does not work for me, maybe they relocated?