# how to create mpeg video out of list of images using java

Tags: java, jpeg, mpeg

how to create `mpeg` video out of list of images using `java` codes !
I've tried to use `DataOutputStream` but it didn't work and here is a bit of my code :

```
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("s.mpeg"));
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("image.jpg"));
        while (dis.available()>0) 
        {              
            byte data[] = new byte[ dis.available()];
            dis.read(data);
            dos.write(data);
        }
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
```

any help please !

Comment: A video file is wayyy more complicated that a bunch of images grafted together. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985706/how-to-create-mpeg-video-from-images-in-java.

Comment: What you have done so far is just copying the image data into a new file with the extension `mpeg`. I am afraid video processing is not as simple as you think (concatenated image data).

Comment: is there any api you know that help me in creating a video from images !!

Comment: We gave you two links. You have to do your part of the job.

Comment: Okay man thanks a lot I'll try and I'll tell you the result

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f  that ffmpeg command on cli will make a movie from a series of  jpg's that have fileName matching the CLI pattern.