# How to build xuggler for Android?

Tags: android, video, xuggler

I need to split frames from video and get the different images in Android API for that I had gone with the help of SDK Mediamatadatareteriver.

Duration of video is 127040(2:07sec) I splited as 32 frames but the problem in that was it repeats the same first image for all my remaining 32 frames.

To fix that I'd tried a lot but their is no use now I just want to go on with XUggler Library file with the help of Latest Version by using Windows 7 (64 bit).

so if anyone have idea about this or any other alternative method to solve this issues please help me Friends.

Answer (score -1):

There is an explanation on xuggler-users group from Art Clarke :

```
       I have not attempted to port xuggler to android, but if someone is interested 

`all jvm related code is in the 'ferry' module. Memory mgmt is particularly`

     complicated and hard, but in theory a port would be possible
```